# Is there a way to avoid index creation on application startup using Mongo repository?

Tags: javers

`JaversBuilder.build()` always calls `MongoRepository.ensureSchema()` to execute `createIndex()` for `jv_snapshots`, even when the indexes already exists.

Particularly, the `createIndex` permission was revoked because this command blocks all other operations on the Mongo instance (not only the database, like in MongoDB documentation) when executed in foreground.

Maybe `ensureSchema` could be called when configuring Javers for the application, outside `JaversBuilder.build()`. Example:

```java
@Bean
public Javers javers() {
    MongoRepository repository = new MongoRepository(mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName));
    Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().registerJaversRepository(repository).build();
    repository.ensureSchema();
    return javers;
}
```

It is appropriate to suggest the removal of the call to `ensureSchema` from `JaversBuilder.build()` or is there another way to avoid index creation on startup in a non Spring Boot application?

Comment: Maybe JaVers should check if an index exists and try to create it olny if it dosn't exists?

Comment: Yes. This is a better solution. My suggestion was based on my workaround.